Python sort lib different behavior with different comparing functions, some comparing function will not work
I want get a max alphabetically order by sub string, so I need to have a comparing method.
For the comparing function function
from functools import cmp_to_key
def compare(a,b):
    print(a,b, a+b,b+a,a+b>b+a) 
    return (a+b)>(b+a) # first comparing function

def sortArr(ls):
    ls = sorted(ls,key =cmp_to_key(compare),reverse=True)
    return "".join(ls)

ls = ["8","81","82","829"]
print(sortArr(ls))

Which will output as:
82 829 82829 82982 False
81 82 8182 8281 False
8 81 881 818 True
88182829

But using comparing function as:
from functools import cmp_to_key
def compare(a,b):
    print(a,b, a+b,b+a,a+b>b+a)
    return int(a+b) -int(b+a) # second comparing function

def sortArr(ls):
    ls = sorted(ls,key =cmp_to_key(compare),reverse=True)
    return "".join(ls)

ls = ["8","81","82","829"]
print(sortArr(ls))

the output is
82 829 82829 82982 False
81 82 8182 8281 False
8 81 881 818 True
8 82 882 828 True
8 829 8829 8298 True
88298281

Apparently the second sort function is what's needed ( the final string 88182829 < 88298281 ). the first function didn't do all comparing use first element.
So why the first comparing function didn't work?

"Apparently the second sort function is what's needed.": needed for what? What is it you want to achieve?

"didn't work": what does that mean? Both work.

I want get an max dictionary order string joined by sub string  by sorting method, the first implementation of sort function can't work well. For the sort function can't return 0 to sort lib, so it will not work well.

I suggest you edit this information into your question, as future readers will not find this question if they look for something like that.

I want get an max dictionary order string joined by sub string  by sorting method, the first implementation of sort function can't work well. For the sort function can't return -1 to sort lib, so it will not work well. According the answer, the function which return True or False, when it pass to sort lib, which will conver to 1 and 0, there is not -1 value.  So the sort will not work.

Do you know how to edit your question? Comments should not be used for answering, as they may be deleted any time. Anyway, I found this question was already asked before, so I put a banner at the top.

I removed the text that answers the question. It does not belong in the question post.

It's unclear why you might expect the first function to work. An old-style comparison function has to work like so:

cmp(x, y) is negative if and only if x < y.
cmp(x, y) is 0 if and only if x == y.
cmp(x, y) is strictly positive (> 0) if and only if x > y.

Given that, your return (a+b)>(b+a) doesn't appear to make sense. It can only return True or False, which act like 1 and 0, respectively. So it's impossible for it to return a result which will be interpreted as meaning a is less than b.

I got your point. When I change the function as below, the sort will work
def compare(a,b):
if (a+b)==(b+a):return 0
return 1 if  (a+b)>(b+a) else -1
